# PHP: RSA Encrypt ONLY using modulus and exponent

Tags: php

now , i ONLY have the modulus and exponent.

How should i do to encrypt using modulus and exponent in PHP?

It costed me much time that serching the answer in internet, but all was useless.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Most functions will want the Public Key in some specific format (standard or not), but all those formats are is particular ways of representing the modulus and exponent; you just need to construct such a format from the representation you currently have. A quick search turned up [this discussion of formats supported by a particular library](http://www.cryptosys.net/pki/rsakeyformats.html); it has references to the various standards defining formats, including [this XML-based spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xkms2/) which might give you somewhere to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using phpseclib, a pure [PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html),

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); 
$rsa->loadKey(
    array(
        'e' => new Math_BigInteger('...'),
        'n' => new Math_BigInteger('...')
    )
);

$rsa->encrypt('...');
```

A discussion of the various number formats supported by Math_BigInteger can be found here:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/examples.html#constructor

Note that phpseclib follows the PKCS1 standards and pads plaintext's. Since it sounds like your RSA key isn't formated in an industry standard way I'm going to guess you're not wanting to use industry standard padding either. So what you'll want to do is this:

```
$plaintext = new Math_BigInteger('aaaaaa');
echo $rsa->_exponentiate($plaintext)->toBytes();
```

Do note that doing RSA encryption like that is quite insecure but I'll leave that consideration up to you.