# How do I encrypt text using phpseclib and RSA with only the modulus and exponent?

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I tried the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289597/php-rsa-encrypt-only-using-modulus-and-exponent), but it did not work:

```
$rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(
    array(
        'e' => new \Math_BigInteger($exponent),
        'n' => new \Math_BigInteger($modulus)
    )
);
$cipher = $rsa->encrypt($text, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
```

My modulus is a 512-character hexadecimal number and my exponent is 10001. I've tried many different solutions, but I haven't found one that made this work. I'm receiving this error:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in BigInteger.php on line 547
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using strings representing hexadecimal numbers you should tell that to Math_BigInteger

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(
    array(
        'e' => new Math_BigInteger($exponent, 16),
        'n' => new Math_BigInteger($modulus, 16)
    )
);
```

Comment: Ah, the last thing I tried before I went to sleep was making `n` base 16, but I made `e` base 2! What a simple mistake. Thank you.